# login into windows 10 desktop via commandline

Tags: windows, session, ssh, automation, sshd

In my home automation scenario, i can logoff my windows session with the "logoff" command from a remote computer. The remote computer connects to sshd on the windows machine and runs

```
ssh myaccount@remotee logoff <session_id>
```

So I am wondering, if windows 10 has booted and the password prompt shows up, can I login via a remote command. There seems not to be a "logon /user" command in windows 10